# N-Queen Lisp (1- n) mean?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun queens (n &optional (m n))
   (if (zerop n)
       (list nil)
       (loop for solution in (queens (1- n) m) ;; <=== what does the (1- n) mean?
          nconc (loop for new-col from 1 to m
                     when (loop for row from 1 to n
                                 for col in solution
                                 always (/= new-col col (+ col row) (- col row)))
                     collect (cons new-col solution)))))

(defun print-solution (solution)
   (loop for queen-col in solution
      do (loop for col from 1 to (length solution)
              do (write-char (if (= col queen-col) #\Q #\.)))
         (terpri))
   (terpri))

(defun print-queens (n)
   (mapc #'print-solution (queens n)))
```

hi, can anyone explain to me this N-Queen algo why is there a (1- n)? what does the "1-" part and &optional syntax?

thank you,

Comment: [It just substracts 1 from n.](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_1pl_1_.htm). Optional parameters come after the `&optional` keyword.

Comment: but shoulden is be written as (- n 1) in lisp language? do you mind explain a little more? i kind of new to lisp language, thank you

Comment: Apparently it doesn't matter. I believe `1+` and `1-` are special, though I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is explained clearly in the documentation on [1-](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_1pl_1_.htm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1-` is a function that subtracts one from its parameter.

`&optional` states that optional parameters will follow. Usually the default value is `nil`, but if you specify it as a list - i.e. `(m n)` then the parameter defaults to the second value in the list (in this case m defaults to n if a second parameter is not passed).

Comment: Sorry, could you give a little more explanation for the (m n) part? do you mean that (queen (-1 n) m)) refer passing in a n-1 value and a list to the function? 

could you to me the queens function? i am kind lost when tracing the code.

Comment: @theStress If I have a function defined as `(defun myfun (a &optional (b 5)))` and I call `(myfun 4)`, it will actually call `(myfun 4 5)`. However, I am free to just say something like `(myfun 4 7)`, and then `b` will not be 5.